# Junit test case using mockito for Exception handling

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method like below for which I have to write the test case for FileNotFoundException

```
public ResponseEntity<ChefAgent> getClientDetails(String clientName) {

    LogImpl.setLogger(className,
            "Entered RESTAPI method to getClientDetails");
    ResponseEntity<ChefAgent> response = null;
    ResponseBean responseBean = null;
    ErrorBean errorBean = new ErrorBean();
    try {

        requestBean.setChefApi(ChefServiceProvider.getApi());
        requestBean.setService(NodeManagementConstants.CLIENT_DETAILS);
        requestBean.setClientName(clientName);
        responseBean = delegator.handleRequest(requestBean);

        if (null != responseBean.getChefAgent()) {
            response = new ResponseEntity<ChefAgent>(
                    responseBean.getChefAgent(), new HttpHeaders(),
                    HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            response = new ResponseEntity<ChefAgent>(
                    responseBean.getChefAgent(), new HttpHeaders(),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        ChefServiceProvider.getClose();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LogImpl.setWarning(Segregator.class, e.getMessage());

        LogImpl.setWarning(className, "error occured");

        errorBean.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR
                .getErrorCode());
        errorBean.setErrorMessage(ErrorCode.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR
                .getMessage());
        ChefAgent agent = new ChefAgent();
        agent.setErrorBean(errorBean);
        response = new ResponseEntity<ChefAgent>(agent, new HttpHeaders(),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return response;
    }
    catch (CustomException e) {
        LogImpl.setWarning(Segregator.class, e.getMessage());
    }
    LogImpl.setLogger(Segregator.class,
            "Ended RESTAPI method to getClientDetails");

    return response;
}
```

Here the method ChefServiceProvider.getApi() have some FileInputStream operation and for which it throws FileNotFoundException. I'm not able to create a scenario in mockito where I can test the catch block in method getClientDetails(String clientName). Tried something like below

```
@Test()
public void testGetClientDetailsFileNotFoundException() throws Exception {

    String clientName = "client";
    ChefAgent chefAgent = new ChefAgent();
    List<ChefClientBean> chefClientBean = new ArrayList<ChefClientBean>();
    chefClientBean.add(new ChefClientBean());
    chefAgent.setChefClientList(chefClientBean);
    responseBean.setChefAgent(chefAgent);
    ResponseEntity<ChefAgent> response;

    try {
        Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(ChefServiceProvider.getApi());
        response = cloudManagementHelper.getClientDetails(clientName);
        Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    } 
}
```

But it gives error like

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:  Argument passed to
>   when() is not a mock!

### Please let me know what is the correct way to do this.

I'm using below code to mock the method

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ChefServiceProvider.class);
PowerMockito.when(ChefServiceProvider.getApi()).thenReturn(chefApi);

Mockito.when(ChefServiceProvider.getApi()).thenThrow(
        new FileNotFoundException());
```

But then I'm getting error like

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.

Comment: That looks like two questions now and I'd split up otherwise the answers are going to be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PowerMockito:

- You need to add annotation `@PrepareForTest(ChefServiceProvider.class)`
- You need to add annotation `@RunWiths(PowerMockRunner.class)`
- Then you can use: `PowerMockito.mockStatic(ChefServiceProvider.class);`
- You don't need to use `PowerMockito.when(ChefServiceProvider.getApi()).thenReturn(chefApi);` - You can delete this line
- You can use: `PowerMockito.when(ChefServiceProvider.getApi()).thenThrow(new FileNotFoundException());`

Comment: Remember to use PowerMockito.when - not  Mockito.when for static method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you mocked `ChefServiceProvider.getApi()` ? Mockito is telling you that you've not passed it a mocked object.

Native Mockito won't let you mock static methods. I would perhaps check out [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) for additional features allowing you to do this sort of stuff, and investigate [inversion-of-control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) for the future to allow you to inject such dependencies.

> PowerMock is a framework that extend other mock libraries such as
>   EasyMock with more powerful capabilities. PowerMock uses a custom
>   classloader and bytecode manipulation to enable mocking of static
>   methods, constructors, final classes and methods, private methods,
>   removal of static initializers and more

When I've used PowerMock I've used it to create a unit test around poorly written code, and then refactored the code to a better pattern, using PowerMock to perform regression tests. Once refactored I can then use standard Mockito practises and remove the need for PowerMock.

Comment: I'm using below code to mock the method   PowerMockito.mockStatic(ChefServiceProvider.class);
  PowerMockito.when(ChefServiceProvider.getApi()).thenReturn(chefApi);

  Mockito.when(ChefServiceProvider.getApi()).thenThrow(
    new FileNotFoundException());
But here I'm getting error like --org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.